# Python searching for a number from first row in sheets

Tags: python, google-sheets, gspread

I have a google sheets connected to my python code
I would like to have python search only the first row for a number
For example like if input is '3' then find 3 from first row then put the date or something
This is my code:

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import datetime

scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets', "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secret.json.json',scope)
a = raw_input("Type your Number")

client = gspread.authorize(credentials)
date = datetime.datetime.now()
sheet = client.open('hi').sheet1
if raw_input == '1':
    sheet.update_acell('B2', 'This Value for B2')
else: 
    print('r')
#print(sheet.get_all_records())
#sheet.append_row([str(date), 'this goes'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's store the values of the first row in a list and traverse it to find the match and get the column number to update that column.

I've tried to correct the code. Please try to run this, it should work for you. :)

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import datetime

scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets', 
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file", 
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secret.json.json',scope)
a = raw_input("Type your Number")

client = gspread.authorize(credentials)
date = datetime.datetime.now()
sheet = client.open('hi').sheet1
values_list = sheet.row_values(1) #Get first row values as a list
col_num = 1 #To get the column number
flag = 0
#Traverse the list to find the match
for item in values_list:
    if a == item:
        flag=1            
        break
    col_num = col_num + 1
if flag == 1:
    sheet.update_cell(1, col_num, 'Updated Value')
else:
    print('r')
#print(sheet.get_all_records())
#sheet.append_row([str(date), 'this goes']
```